# Function returning lookup value from a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to build a Power Query function that will return a value from a table looked up based on an input parameter.  Eg.

```
Table:
Name    Team
George  Server
June    DBA
```

Now I want to supply Name to the function and return the position.  Source table is a table defined in the same Excel workbook.  I started with that but not sure where I am failing:

```
(EmployeeName as text) =>

let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Employees"]}[Content],
    EmployeeRow = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = EmployeeName)),    
    Result = Record.Field(EmployeeRow, [Team])
in
    Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected function is:

```
(EmployeeName as text) =>

let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Employees"]}[Content],
    EmployeeRow = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Name],EmployeeName)),
    EmployeeRecord = Table.SingleRow(EmployeeRow),
    Result = Record.Field(EmployeeRecord, "Team")
in
    Result
```

The problem was that I need to reference column in double quotes and not square brackets in Record.Field() function.